# How to define a meshgrid (x,y) between the intersection of two oblique lines.

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

[image: The two oblique lines]

How can I create a meshgrid to draw a 3d surface in a domain (zone 1) defined by the intersection of two oblique lines in Matlab (see attached figure)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEH3H.jpg).
The variables  0

Answer (score 2):

the matlab `meshgrid` outputs two rectangular grids.

If you just want to display the surface in zone $1$ and not the others,

`[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.01:3);
z = your_function(x,y).*((y > 0.5*x + 1) & (y > 6*x - 2));
surf(z)`

should do it (I'm just using a logical condition to mask off the area of interest, and set the function equal to zero elsewhere).

Comment: Might it be possible with Matlab to limit the function in the zone 1 and avoided putting the function equal to zero elsewhere?

Comment: What are you trying to do that this solution doesn't accomplish? The `surf` function (as well as `imagesc`, `contour`, etc.) expect a rectangular matrix as input. If the surface $z = 0$ is getting in the way of viewing your surface, then set the other zones to some lower value (i.e. `z = z_min*ones(length(x)); z = z + (your_function(x,y) - z_min).*((y > ...`)

Comment: Or set it to `NaN`. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065203/80812) to the OP to a virtually identical question.

Comment: @horchler: I do not understand what I have to get into Nan
NaN = vector(x) or the limit value of x?